# Read binary chunks with VLC using Python

Tags: python, vlc, libvlc

I would like to ask if it's possible to read binary flow with VLC.
I managed to do it by writing the data into a file and then reading it with vlc, but can I do it without using a file as a buffer to write the flow?

Here's an example

```
with open('filetest','wb') as videofile:    
for i in result:      # result is a generator object
        print i
        videofile.write(i)
```

So while this function is writing the flow, an other thread is waiting for the file to be big enough to open it with VLC.

Is there a way to bypass writing to the file to have something that looks like this?

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["vlc.exe",binaryflow])
```

When doing some researches the module "libvlc" comes up frequently. I riffled the methods and couldn't find something that could help, am I looking the wrong way?

Thanks

Comment: I have no experience of libvlc but most these kind of command line applications operate on UNIX pipes and you can create (named) pipe in your Python process to pass data forth and back.